# URL Rewrite & Redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

I have a query regarding URL rewriting and redirection that I can't find the answer to (if there is even a solution to this)

Currently I'm working with a website that lists locations and as such accesses them using the following URL with an ID as the variable (using "1" as an example to pull the corrasponding record from a MySQL database);

> location.php?location=1

The variable has since been changed from a number to a URL slug (which is now used to pull the record from the MySQL database), so for example;

> location.php?location=exeter-devon-uk

... and the URL above is now also rewritten using a .htaccess file to be;

> /location/exeter-devon-uk

All this works perfectly fine.

Now my problem is this ... Google (and other search engines) have already indexed/crawled the website in question so have all the old links with the original URL of - location.php?location=1(or whatever number) - and these obviously no longer work because the code works on the newer database URL slug and not the ID number.

I know with URL rewriting you are supposed to point the old URL to the new URL and do a 301 permanent redirect ... but I don't know how to do this (can it even be done?) for directing the old ID number to a slug, without knowing how to relate the two??

Comment: You don't have **any** way to relate IDs to new strings (ID is not preserved in DB anymore) ?

Comment: Well yes, an ID will always be associated with a record in a database, you can't do without one ... but ... URL redirection is carried out in the .htaccess file and this obviously isn't aware of 1. the PHP code, or 2. the database, so I can't see how to do this

Comment: You have two options: modify the php so that it still responds to `location.php?location=...`, with 301 redirect to proper slug url, or you can export all `id slug` pairs to simple plaintext file and use that in rewrite rule. I think that first option is proper, but I can help with the second if that is quicker for you

Comment: Also, to use  [RewriteMap](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html) file, you need to have access to server .conf files, it will not work from htaccess

Comment: exporting all id and slug pairs would just create a huge .htaccess full of redirects wouldn't it ... there are nearly 16,000 plus records at the moment so that would be a HUGE file

Comment: No, it can not go in .htaccess (see [this](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html)). If slug+id is 30bytes, it will be ~500kB, which maybe isn't that much.